# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token export (Redux)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I'm trying to create a reducer in react with the code below, but I keep getting this error in the console:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token export

```
const INIT_STATE = [];

export default (state = INIT_STATE, action) {

  switch(action.type) {
    default: state
  }
}
```

I'm still trying to figure my way around redux and don't know exactly how to solve this error.

Comment: You seem to have forgotten the `function` keyword

Answer (score 1):

This happens when you have multiple exports on the same file and you add a default export to one of them , so the solution is either to export one module by using `export default` or  just `export` if you want to export multiple objects , functions...etc in the same file

Another thing to mention is the way you call a function , es6 introduces the arrow function

instead of this  `(arg1 , arg2 ){ .... }` you should do this `(arg1 , arg2 ) => {.....}`

so for your case

```
   const INIT_STATE = [];

export (state = INIT_STATE, action) => {

switch(action.type) {
    default: state
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you're trying to run that code without compiling it first.  The ES6 import/export syntax is still not natively supported in most environments - ES6 modules have to be compiled to another format first, usually using Babel.

Answer (score 0):

This is improper syntax. You need to add the function keyword before the function signature, or define it as an arrow function like Sam suggested.

i.e. 
`export default function (state = INIT_STATE, action) {...}` or `export default (state = INIT_STATE, action) => {...}`, instead of `export default (state = INIT_STATE, action) {...}`